# Error using OpenCV, program closes unexpectedly

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Posting on behalf of https://stackexchange.com/users/17689558/evan-kiffel since it will for some reason will not let him post a question (it is saying that he can only post once every 90 minutes)

I am trying to run a shape detector program to open up my webcam and search for shapes. When I do this, the webcam opens but after a couple of seconds closes and opens up the mac error window. How can I fix this code/change something on my computer to fix this problem? Thanks for the help!

Here is what the error looks like:[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgupB.jpg)

```
import cv2
import numpy as np



def nothing(x):
    # any operation
    pass

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cv2.namedWindow("Trackbars")
cv2.createTrackbar("L-H", "Trackbars", 0, 180, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("L-S", "Trackbars", 66, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("L-V", "Trackbars", 134, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("U-H", "Trackbars", 180, 180, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("U-S", "Trackbars", 255, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar("U-V", "Trackbars", 243, 255, nothing)

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    l_h = cv2.getTrackbarPos("L-H", "Trackbars")
    l_s = cv2.getTrackbarPos("L-S", "Trackbars")
    l_v = cv2.getTrackbarPos("L-V", "Trackbars")
    u_h = cv2.getTrackbarPos("U-H", "Trackbars")
    u_s = cv2.getTrackbarPos("U-S", "Trackbars")
    u_v = cv2.getTrackbarPos("U-V", "Trackbars")

    lower_red = np.array([l_h, l_s, l_v])
    upper_red = np.array([u_h, u_s, u_v])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
    kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, kernel)

    # Contours detection
    if int(cv2.__version__[0]) > 3:
        # Opencv 4.x.x
        contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    else:
        # Opencv 3.x.x
        _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for cnt in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.02*cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)
        x = approx.ravel()[0]
        y = approx.ravel()[1]

        if area > 400:
            cv2.drawContours(frame, [approx], 0, (0, 0, 0), 5)

            if len(approx) == 3:
                cv2.putText(frame, "Triangle", (x, y), font, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            elif len(approx) == 4:
                cv2.putText(frame, "Rectangle", (x, y), font, 1, (0, 0, 0))
            elif 10 < len(approx) < 20:
                cv2.putText(frame, "Circle", (x, y), font, 1, (0, 0, 0))


    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: It is too long to put, but here is a link to it: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HFTUFhkH6-gusI2dmZ0OcWB3JnqlRkD9bccvAa2RI38/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Check if the frame is valid after `cap.read()`: don't let the loop execute if frame is `None`.

Comment: It is displaying as true and the camera does open, it just not open a window before it crashes

Comment: Start commenting out lines of code from the loop until you find the line that makes the problem go away.

Comment: We tried doing a totally new code using cv2 and it gives the same error as soon as you call cap.read()

Comment: Perhaps it's time to update the OpenCV version that is being used. I mean, assuming you guys wrote a minimal application that retrieves frames from the camera and displays them on a window. Otherwise, it can still be something else in your logic. What OpenCV version do you guys have and what operating system is this running on?

Comment: He is new to python so just installed both the newest version of python and opencv. I will double check when I see him later that an older version is not installed, but I installed the same way on my mac and it works fine.

Comment: Version 4.2.0 in cv2   and Python 3.7.6

Comment: We found out it runs if you take out the trackbars, cv2.imshow("Frame", frame), and 
    cv2.imshow("Mask", mask)

Comment: We ran from terminal and it gives the following error: qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Abort trap: 6

Comment: (re)install Qt. Make sure you don't have more than one Qt version installed on the system.

Comment: We never installed Qt, but just tried installing it using pip3 install PyQt5. Is this the correct Qt or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this is a permissions issue. We were able to run the program by going to the terminal and running using sudo.